# Is CoreBluetooth able to connect to a Wii balance board?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, bluetooth

I would like to create an app for iphone to use wii balance board as a scale. I found a beautiful and working project for mac os x on github (wiiscale). I' beginning to convert it for iOS, but I have a doubt. Maybe with the iOS framework CoreBluetooth (the bluetooth framework for iOS) it is not possible to connect to the Balance Board? the mac os x project uses IOBluetooth framework, which is not available to iOS ...

Comment: It depends on the doc of the Wii Balance. If it's Bluetooth Low-Energy, it should be able to with CoreBluetooth.framework...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you mean that with CoreBluetooth is only for LE Bluetooth? And that I can develope iphone apps that use only LE Bluetooth? Not standard bluetooth?

Comment: CoreBluetooth is only for BLE (it's one of the first line of the doc). I don't think that the Wii Balance respect the MFI (that should be used for classical Bluetooth devices).